# How to add a new database in existing failover group in Azure Managed Instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have an Azure Managed instance with multiple databases, which are in a failover group. I need to restore a new database to this Managed Instance and I would like to know if there are any additional steps required to add the new database in existing failover group.

I tested this in other environment and the new database was not automatically synced to failover group. I had to re-create the failover group after restoring the database on primary node and after recreating, the new database started seeding on the secondary.

Is there any other way to add new database in failover group other than re-creating it as recreating failover group would also require the other databases to be synced again? I can find ways to add new database in failover group for Azure SQL database but nothing for Managed Instance.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7629/add-azure-sql-database-to-existing-auto-failover-group/ check if this helps you?